# Areca Palm leaves looking weird

Tags: diagnosis, areca-palm

Does anyone know why my Areca’s leaves looks like this? [image]

Comment: Root problem. Dryness? Overwatering? Roots are not happy somehow. Snip ends at an angle for aesthetics.